# postgresql: several tables in from statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I have seen such query:

```
SELECT a.city
FROM airports a
EXCEPT
SELECT arr.city
FROM airports dep, airports arr, flights f
WHERE dep.city = 'Москва'
AND f.departure_airport = dep.airport_code
AND f.arrival_airport = arr.airport_code;
```

I don't understand part `FROM airports dep, airports arr, flights f` - is it some kind of syntax sugar for full join?

Comment: It's the old style of joining (its an `inner join`), it is not generally advised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are *implicit* inner joins. The table names are enumerated in the `from` clause, and the join conditions are placed in the `where` clause.

This is much simpler expressed with standard, explicit joins:

```
SELECT arr.city
FROM airports dep
INNER JOIN airports arr ON f.arrival_airport = arr.airport_code
INNER JOIN flights f ON f.departure_airport = dep.airport_code
WHERE dep.city = 'Москва'
```

Side note: as I understand your question, you could express the whole query with `not exists` rather than  `except`:

```
select a.city
from airports a
where not exists (
    select 1
    from flights f
    inner join airports adep on f.departure_airport = adep.airport_code
    where adep.city = 'Москва' and f.arrival_airport = a.airport_code
)
```